# How can I get a BIGINT sequence value and put it into a VARCHAR?

Tags: sql-server

I created this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TestIdMaster]
    AS BIGINT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CACHE;
```

I know I can get the value out like this:

```
 DECLARE @TestId AS INT
    = NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.TestIdMaster
```

However I want to use this value in a varchar and want to append a hyphen to it. So how can I get the value and convert it to a varchar ?

Comment: So the whole question is just "how to cast an integer to a varchar"? If so - why does the 95% of the question it takes irrelevant info about sequences? Does it really matter where exactly an integer comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @TestId AS INT = NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.TestIdMaster
SET @v = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@TestId) + '-'
```